# JSON to typescript class, interface?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am trying to develop a weppapp with Angular2 & Typescript. I have a json like this :

```
{
"homeMenu":{
    "aname1":{
        "title":"text",
        "route":"myroute"
    },
    "aname2":{
        "title":"text",
        "route":"myroute"
    },
    "aname3":{
        "title":"text",
        "route":"myroute"
    },
    "aname4":{
        "title":"text",
        "route":"myroute",
        "homeMenu":{
            "aname41":{
                "title":"text",
                "route":"myroute"
            },
            "aname42":{
                "title":"text",
                "route":"myroute"
            }
        }
    },
    "aname5":{
        "title":"text",
        "route":"myroute"
    }
}}
```

I want with some class or interface i don't know, generate this type of json. I   tried but no success, for me I need 3 one with all menu, a class menu, and class submenu. i have something little similar but i don't have for example "aname1", "aname2" on my json...

at the beginning I thought it was not a valid JSON I have test with a json validator and he is valid. So i need some help to achieve this
thanks :)

Comment: So a menu item can be a menu itself? Is it always `homeMenu`? Because the top menu is `homeMenu` and then in `aname4` there's another `homeMenu`.

Comment: Yeah, but aname41 and 42 don't have homemenu. it's the last child

Comment: But what are the rules? Is it always `homeMenu` or can it be any string?

Comment: always homeMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your json and the answers to my comments, using interfaces you can do:

```
interface HomeMenu {
    [name: string]: MenuItem;
}

interface MenuItem {
    title: string;
    route: string;
    homeMenu?: HomeMenu;
}

interface Menu {
    homeMenu: HomeMenu;
}

let json: Menu = {
    "homeMenu": {
        "aname1": {
            "title": "text",
            "route": "myroute"
        },
        "aname2": {
            "title": "text",
            "route": "myroute"
        },
        "aname3": {
            "title": "text",
            "route": "myroute"
        },
        "aname4": {
            "title": "text",
            "route": "myroute",
            "homeMenu": {
                "aname41": {
                    "title": "text",
                    "route": "myroute"
                },
                "aname42": {
                    "title": "text",
                    "route": "myroute"
                }
            }
        },
        "aname5": {
            "title": "text",
            "route": "myroute"
        }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20HomeMenu%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20MenuItem%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MenuItem%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20homeMenu%3F%3A%20HomeMenu%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Menu%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20homeMenu%3A%20HomeMenu%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20json%3A%20Menu%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22homeMenu%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aname1%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22text%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22route%22%3A%20%22myroute%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aname2%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22text%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22route%22%3A%20%22myroute%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aname3%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22text%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22route%22%3A%20%22myroute%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aname4%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22text%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22route%22%3A%20%22myroute%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22homeMenu%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aname41%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22text%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22route%22%3A%20%22myroute%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aname42%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22text%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22route%22%3A%20%22myroute%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aname5%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22text%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22route%22%3A%20%22myroute%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: Thanks !!, but here  your variable contains already the menu,
I can use it without that ? and generate with a template angular ?
like  test = new menu(aname) then  test.addMenuItem(title,route) ? and at the end when i use json.stringify(HomeMenu) i gonna have the json complete ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you.  Can you explain you situation better?

Comment: Ok sorry, I have this json. i want develop one app  with angular2 & typescript and my goal is with a GUI you type your menu, submenu for this menus, an another menu... at the end when you submit, the code generate the json with all the informations from the previous step.
I tried something with some class example : 
    this.Menu = new Menu(this.name, this.isRedacMenu);
    this.Navigation.addMenu(this.Menu);
and
    this.Smenu = new Smenu(this.sname);
    this.Navigation.homeMenu[this.index].addSMenu(this.Smenu);
But I don't have the same json.
Can I have the same json with your code?

Comment: Ok I didn't know how works interface. Now I have another problem, How i can add another menuItem in the homeMenu Object ? i don't have push or something, i tried to extend of array but no success, Always index undefined :(
Thanks in advance